# How to get data stored in a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM element of class `bar` that stores data `foo`, which is the id of another DOM element.

```
<div class="bar" data="foo">...</div>
```

When I hover over such element, I want to get the DOM element that the data (id) points to. I did this:

```
$(".bar").hover(function(){alert($("#"+$(this).data()));});
```

But when I hover, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing the `data()` method with the element's `data` attribute.

The `data()` method returns an unrelated object of data attached to the element and not the string you are looking for.

---

**Solution 1 - data as an attribute**

To get the value you're looking for in your example, you should query the attribute with the `attr()` method:

```
$(".bar").hover(function(){alert($("#"+$(this).attr('data')));});
```

---

**Solution 2 - data as an object**

Using the `data()` method you can manually attach information to the element:

```
$('.bar').data('data','foo');
$(".bar").hover(function(){alert($("#"+$(this).data('data')));});
```

Note how in this case `'data'` is just an arbitrary name for a key in the element's data object. For more on the `data()` method see [the jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

---

**Solution 3 - data as an object and HTML5 attribute**

I believe your original intention was to query the `data` attribute as an HTML5 data-attribute, that according to [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) should be `automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object`.

However, note that according to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes), HTML5 data-attributes are expected to have a `data-` prefix. So in order for your example to work, the attribute cannot be named `data` but rather `data-something`. For example:

```
<div class="bar" data-something="foo">...</div>
```

Which you can then access with jQuery's `data()` method:

```
 $(".bar").hover(function(){alert($("#"+$(this).data('something')));});
```

Note how `data-something` is accessed with `data('someting')`, since jQuery automatically removes the `data-` prefix.

Comment: Why can't I use `data()` in this case?

Comment: @sawa See updated answer again. I believe this answers your original question better.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Thanks for even more detailed explanation. Something after `data`, that was what I was missing.

Comment: This is the best summary I've seen on that subject. Well done!

Answer (score 4):

you need to access the attribute with the attr function.

```
$(".bar").hover(function() {
     alert($("#"+$(this).attr('data')));
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know no one is asking for this, but here is how to do this in modern browsers without jQuery:

```js
for (bar of document.getElementsByClassName('bar')) {
  bar.addEventListener('hover', e => alert(
    document.getElementById(e.target.attributes.data.value)
  ))
}
```